# How to create "More" button on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React components :

***Main.jsx***

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { Preloader } from "../Preloader";
import { Pokemons } from "../Pokemons";
import { LoadMore } from "../LoadMore";

function Main() {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [pokemonsPerPage] = useState("20");
  const [pokemonOffset] = useState("0");

  useEffect(function getPokemons() {
    fetch(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${pokemonsPerPage}&offset=${pokemonOffset}`
    )
      .then((responce) => responce.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.results && setPokemons(data.results);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className="container content">
      {loading ? <Preloader /> : <Pokemons pokemons={pokemons} />}
      <LoadMore />
    </main>
  );
}

export { Main };
```

***LoadMore.jsx***

```
import React from 'react'

function LoadMore() {
  return (
    <div className="button_container">
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" id="more">
        More...
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

export { LoadMore };
```

I have created a button in the component. After clicking on it, the next 20 elements should be loaded. I created `const [pokemonsPerPage] = useState("20");`  and `const [pokemonOffset] = useState("0");`  in order to substitute these values into the request. The first is responsible for the number of objects on the page, the second is responsible for which element to start counting from. That is, now 20 elements are being output, starting from the very first one. (If you change  `const [pokemonOffset] = useState("0");` to 20, then the output will start from 21 elements). I'm sure that this is necessary for implementation, but I don't know what to do next

Help me complete this functionality

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your Main.jsx should look like.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { Preloader } from "../Preloader";
import { Pokemons } from "../Pokemons";
import { LoadMore } from "../LoadMore";

function Main() {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [pokemonsPerPage] = useState(20);

  const [page,setPage] = useState(1);

  function getPokemons(pokemonOffset) {
    fetch(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${pokemonsPerPage}&offset=${pokemonOffset}`
    )
      .then((responce) => responce.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.results && setPokemons(data.results);
        setLoading(false);
      });
 }


  useEffect(() => {

    const offset= page*pokemonsPerPage -pokemonsPerPage;

    getPokemons(offset);

  }, [page]);

  return (
    <main className="container content">
      {loading ? <Preloader /> : <Pokemons pokemons={pokemons} />}
      <LoadMore next={()=>setPage(p=>p+1)} />
    </main>
  );
}

export { Main };
```

while your Loadmore.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'

function LoadMore(next) {
  return (
    <div className="button_container">
      <a type="button" onclick={next} class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" id="more">
        More...
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

export { LoadMore };
```

Comment: Okay, I have a couple of questions - I'm just learning React, I don't quite understand why the [page] parameter is passed to ```useEffect(() => {

     const offset= page*pokemonsPerPage -pokemonsPerPage;

     getPokemon(offset);

   }, [page]);``` . So, as far as I understand, in ```<LoadMore next={() => setPage((p) => p + 1)} />``` next is an attribute ? If so, it's not entirely clear where to use it.

Comment: The array portion of UseEffect is meant to hold the dependencies needed to rerun the Effect again if any of the dependencies passed in changes.

If no dependency is passed in, the Effect will run once i.e at initial render

Comment: Now it works so that the existing elements are changed to new ones, but I need them to be added to the existing ones. ```const [pokemonOffset] = useState("0");``` which you changed to pages is responsible for displaying from element 1. If each time you add "20" to it, then after each press, new elements will appear. But I don't know how to implement it =(

Comment: if you want the new ones to be added to the existing ones, you'll need to modify `setPokemons` in the `getPokemons` to  `setPokemons(p=>[...p,...data.results])`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. If you have more time, please explain how ```setPokemons((p) => [...p, ...data.results]);``` affects listing items to existing ones.

Comment: ` const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);` holds the store. Each call to `getPokemons` pushes new data to the store(array).

`setPokemons(data.results)` overwrites old data.

`setPokemons(p=>[...p,...data.results])` concatenates old and new data `p` is the old data while `data.results` is the new data. it is the same as doing   `setPokemons(p=>p.concat(data.results))`